# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) error in dart

Tags: dart

When i execute any program in dart it show the below error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>     http://mydomain.com/UrlPro/web/packages/chrome/bootstrap.js

**html**

```dart
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>UrlPro</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="urlpro.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>UrlPro</h1>
  <p>Hello world from Dart!</p>
  <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  <script src="packages/chrome/bootstrap.js" defer></script>
  <script src="urlpro.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
name: UrlPro 
description: A sample Chrome packaged application 
dependencies: 
  browser: any 
transformers:
```

> Dart version Dart Editor version 1.3.6.release (STABLE) Dart SDK version 1.3.6

Comment: Can you please prove more information how you app looks.
`pubspec.yaml`, `index.html`, Dart version.

Comment: Why did you add this line?
`<script src="packages/chrome/bootstrap.js" defer></script>`?
You don't have a package `chrome` in your `pubspec.yaml` dependencies list. Whey do you expect the package `chrome` to contain a file `bootstrap.js` anyway.

Comment: yes it got solved when i removed 
[html]
<script src="packages/chrome/bootstrap.js" defer></script>

Answer (score 0):

You miss the chrome package in your pubspec.yaml.